# I am trying to validate a form with more than one function, but it only calls the last one even if i combine them with a comma

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem validating a form.  When it submits it just runs the last       function.  When i try to combine them with a comma then it just runs them all consecutively. Here is my code:

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
  if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
}

function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
  var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
  var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (atpos< 1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
    alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    return false;
  }
}

function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["message"].value;
  if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("Please Send Us a Message");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You have a lot of function name  `validateForm()` rename the other 2 function and call it in validateForm()

Comment: The last one will override all function before it. Please use different name.

Comment: @Stiger I don't think it'll `override` it'll `overwrite`.

Comment: @Mritunjay sorry for my english, it'll overwrite.

Comment: I've updated my answer for your problem, how can you call on submit.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to have more than one value in one variable, which is not possible. The value you are defining will overwrite the definition which is already there. Change your function names.

Do it like bellow

```
<script>
    function fun1 () {
        alert('in first')
    }
    function fun2 () {
        alert('in Second')
    }
    function fun3 () {
        alert('in third')
    }
</script>
```

call them like bellow `onsubmit` of form

```
<form action="" onsubmit="fun1();fun2();fun3();">
    <input type="submit" value="click">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't handle redeclaring functions with the same name.

What is wrong with:

```
function validateForm() {
    // x is a bad name for the variable.
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
    // x can never be null, BTW.
    if (x === "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    x = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }

    x = document.forms["myForm"]["message"].value;
    if (x === "") {
        alert("Please Send Us a Message");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, works great, i had brackets in between them.(still a noob) but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't name your functions with the same name!** You can call them `validateName`, `validateEmail` and `validateMessage`.

When you declare functions with the same name, the previous functions will be overriden by the last one.

If you want to call one function in `onsubmit`, you can set `onsubmit=validteForm()` and declare `validateForm` as:

```
function validateForm() {
    validateName();
    validateEmail();
    validateMessage();
}
```

Comment: How would you call multiple functions from onsubmit?

Comment: @user3808508 Then you should call a function that calls multiple functions.

Comment: That should probably be `return validateName() && validateEmail() && validateMessage()`. As posted, *validateForm* will always return *undefined* and the form will always submit.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution; you can modify your function(s) to a simple one, like following

```
function validateForm(){
  var x, atpos, dotpos;

  x = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
  if(!x){
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }

  x = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
  atpos = x.indexOf("@");
  dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
  if(atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length){
    alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    return false;
  }

  x = document.forms["myForm"]["message"].value;
  if(!x){
    alert("Please Send Us a Message");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```